# How to align a struct member in D?

Tags: alignment, d, alignof

I tried this

```
struct Foo(T)
{
    align(8) void[T.sizeof] data;
}
```

but

```
static assert(Foo!(int).data.alignof == 8);
```

fails, telling me the alignment is still `1` instead of `8`.

Why is this, and how do I fix it, so that it works for any arbitrary alignment that is a power of 2 (not just 8)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsing the DMD source, it looks like `alignof` doesn't take into account `align` attributes.

Here is where it is handled:

```
... if (ident == Id::__xalignof)
{
    e = new IntegerExp(loc, alignsize(), Type::tsize_t);
}
```

This converts a `.alignof` expression into a `size_t` expression with value `alignsize()`, so let's look at `alignsize()` for a static array:

```
unsigned TypeSArray::alignsize()
{
    return next->alignsize();
}
```

It just gets the alignment of the element type (`void`) in your case.

`void` is handled by `TypeBasic::alignsize()`, which just forwards to `TypeBasic::size(0)`

```
switch (ty)
{
    ...
    case Tvoid:
        size = 1;
        break;
    ...
}
```

Looking at how other types handle `alignof`, it doesn't look like `align` attributes are taken into account at all, but I could be wrong. It may be worth testing the alignment manually.

Comment: lol wait so what does `align` do? Is it just there for decoration? xD

Comment: I think `align` works, but `alignof` just gets the alignment of the type, so they are separate things.

Comment: Weird, I was running into problems that led me to check `alignof`... gotta double-check though..